# Extreme case of semi supervised learning with entire possible population

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, semi-supervised-learning

I don't know how to exactly frame the title of the question.

What I think I have is an extreme case of semi supervised learning. There are 24 features and I have labelled data for around 70 data-points. I also posses 1100 unlabelled points, which in some sense represent the dataset in its entirety.

Example, there are only 1170 types of aliens in the world, and I have some particular label for 70 of them and I want to predict for the rest.

I dabbled with sklearn's label propagation and spreading which are classification algorithms and not regressors (which is what I want).

Intuition tells me, if I already have the global distribution of features of the entire population of aliens, shouldn't prediction be some what easier? Some form of parameter estimation problem?

What packages, papers etc dabble with this issue?

Given I only use the labelled data, it becomes a case of high dimensional (?) supervised learning, which becomes a question in itself.

Also, if it helps, its sparse data, a lot of the values are plain zero.